# jQuery working with dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have so much problem working with dynamic elements in jQuery, that I just need to ask a question. First, a little example from my system:

main.js

```
$(function () {
    renderPlaceList(places);
    setupVoting();
}
```

The two function are in separate files, renderPlace.js is a file, where I am creating a new elements. These elements have class .option and they are then stored in a .places div. So far so good. But then I want to work with these elements in setupVoting():

```
    $('.participants .option').each(function () {
       ...
    })
```

But this just doesn't seem to be working. When I call the code in browser console, it runs just fine. But if it's run while the site is loading, the jQ selector won't find the elements. Where is the catch?

Thanks for your time and answers :)

EDIT

renderPlaces function

```
function renderPlaceList(places) {
    var htmlMeetingPlace = "";
    into = $(".places");
    $(places).each(function(_, d){
        htmlMeetingPlace +=
            "<div class='option' data-meeting_place_id='" + d.id + "'>" +
            "</div>";
    });
    into.fadeOut('slow',function(){
        into.html("");
        into.append(htmlMeetingPlace);
        into.fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
```

Comment: can you show the code for `renderPlaceList` please?

Comment: may be synchronous/asynchronous problem..

Comment: I've added the renderPlaceList function

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that when renderPlaceList return.. $(".places") is not enought formated.. because is still fadeouting..

You can try

```
function renderPlaceList(places) {
var htmlMeetingPlace = "";
into = $(".places");
$(places).each(function(_, d){
    htmlMeetingPlace +=
        "<div class='option' data-meeting_place_id='" + d.id + "'>" +
        "</div>";
  });
  into.fadeOut('slow',function(){
    into.html("");
    into.append(htmlMeetingPlace);
    into.fadeIn('slow');
    setupVoting(); //here!
  });
}
```